# How do I log authorization attempts in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I'm trying to write to a log when I person tries to access a method under an Authorize Attribute. Basically, I want to log if a person uses an invalid token or an expired token. I'm using basic Authentication for JWT

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        cfg.SaveToken = true;

        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudience = jwtAudience,
            ValidIssuer = jwtIssuer,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSecurityKey))
        };

    });
```

Is there a way I can add a piece of code to the authorization check that logs if a authorization attempt was valid and why it wasn't?

Comment: Okay, I clarified the question. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You can inherit `AuthorizeAttribute`, do your logging and call the `base` method

Comment: Which method do I call though. From what I can tell, the AuthorizeAttribute just has two constructors but no actual methods.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have access to the JwtBearerEvents object, which defines a number of events that are raised as the bearer token is processed.

OnAuthenticationFailed
Invoked if exceptions are thrown during request processing. The exceptions will be re-thrown after this event unless suppressed.

OnChallenge 
Invoked before a challenge is sent back to the caller.

OnMessageReceived
Invoked when a protocol message is first received.

OnTokenValidated
Invoked after the security token has passed validation and a ClaimsIdentity has been generated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents?view=aspnetcore-2.0

When initialising the configuration at AddJwtBearer, add the events you'd like to subscribe to,

```
.AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
        {
            // do some logging or whatever...
        }

    };
});
```

Have a look at the source to see when events might be raised,

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs

Comment: I did see that. But is there a way I can see the reason the authentication failed? For example, was the token invalid, or did it expire?

Comment: I think there might have been a mixup between authentication and authorization. JwtBearerEvents handles authentication, but the question was about authorization.

Comment: They mentioned "Basically, I want to log if a person uses an invalid token or an expired token.", so that's at AuthN stage. According to the source, https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/a0b704efbdf924099de908c57087de49c9d12d17/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L113, an invalid token triggers the OnAuthenticationFailed handler

Comment: You need to `return Task.CompletedTask;` if you're not doing anything async https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1680

Comment: @MichaelKargl Did you find out how to intercept the *authorization* request and log any errors?

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if it's already implemented in earlier versions of .NET (Core) but i'm using .NET 6 and i'm able to activate the [logging implemented in .NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/fd1891536f27e959d14a140ff9307b6a21191de9/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L118) by [setting the loglevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-logging) to `Information` for to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` category.

For example in your `appsettings.json`:

```json
 "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      // ...
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information"
    }
  }
```

This gave me the the following log for an expired token (i'm using log4net with a template):

```
INFO [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler] - MESSAGE: Failed to validate the token.
 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredException: IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo: 'System.DateTime', Current time: 'System.DateTime'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateLifetime(Nullable`1 notBefore, Nullable`1 expires, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateLifetime(Nullable`1 notBefore, Nullable`1 expires, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

Of course if you want to be more restrictive you could instead use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler` category in your `appsettings.json`. It's just important to have the loglevel for this class set to `Information` since the generated .NET 6 logs have this loglevel.

Comment: This exactly what I need. I got the error details in the console log. Thanks @Robin Windey

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `Robin Windey` comment I also recommend to use Authorization in `appsettings.json`:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "Information",
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35072575)