# ASP.NET Core : how to log authorization exceptions

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

Is there an elegant way of capturing the **Authorization** exception in ASP.NET without writing any middleware or AuthorizationRequirement class.

I am building the authorization policy in the following way.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Azp, authorizedParties)
            .RequireClaim(CustomClaimNames.Customer)
            .Build();
    });
```

I dont see any OnAuthorizationFailed event just like OnAuthenticationFailed :-)

It is possible to capture **Authentication** exception in the following way.

```
  bearerOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
  {
      OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
      {
        Log.Logger.Error(context.Exception.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
      }
   };
```

But I did not find the similar way to capture Authorization exception.

There is **OnForbidden** event, but the *Exception* property is not available in the **ForbiddenContext** object.

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889771/how-do-i-log-authorization-attempts-in-net-core).

Comment: @YiyiYou Thank you. That link explains how to catch the authentication exception. I am looking for solution to how to capture authorization exception.

Comment: Maybe `JwtBearerEvents.OnForbidden`?

Comment: Did you find a solution?